# How to migrate dynatree to fancytree?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dynatree, fancytree

I have develop a Asp.Net MVC project with dynatree 1.x. But some of features I have need like filtering, Multiple node selection are not available in dynatree. But these are available at fancytree. Now I need to migrate fancytree from dynatree. How can I migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some migration hints in the Fancytree Wiki:
https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/WhatsNew

Comment: I have already seen it. But there is no straight solution. Do you know any other way?